# How to find the point where $N! \geq C^n$?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that the Factorial function grows faster than any exponential function. Therefore there is a point N, where for all $n \geq N, n! \geq C^n$ For all positive real numbers $C$.

Given this, how would you find $N$? 
I tried comparing $C!$ to $C^C$ and $\frac{n!}{C!}$ to ${C^{n-C}}$ (understanding that $C! \leq C^C$, and $\frac{n!}{C!} \geq C^{n-C}$ for all C). I did this because if $n! \geq C^n$, then $\frac{\frac{n!}{C!}}{C^{n-C}} \geq \frac{C^C}{C!}$. So if we can find the value of $\frac{C^C}{C!}$, we would know how much larger $\frac{\frac{n!}{C!}}{C^{n-C}}$ needs to be to fulfill the inequality.
For example, if $C=10$, then $\frac{C^C}{C!} = \frac{10^{10}}{10!} = \frac{10^9}{9!} = \frac{1562500}{567} \approx 2756$. At $n=25,  \frac{\frac{n!}{C!}}{C^{n-C}} \approx 4274$, so $\frac{\frac{n!}{C!}}{C^{n-C}} \geq \frac{C^C}{C!}$ is satisfied and $n! \geq C^n$.
But I couldn’t find a general way to calculate N from C.

So I tried something else. Using the approximation $n! \approx \sqrt{2{\pi}n}(\frac{n}{e})^n$, I set up another equation: $n! \approx \sqrt{2{\pi}n}(\frac{n}{e})^n = C^n$. But when trying to isolate n, the closest I could get is $\frac{\ln(2{\pi}n)}{2n}=\ln(Ce)$.

At this point I’m stuck. I’m only in calc 2, so working from here seems to be beyond my abilities. Can anyone shed some light on this problem in a way that won’t go over my head?

Thanks a lot!

(Sorry for any formatting issues, I haven’t used this system much before)

EDIT: Thanks for the responses, I am trying to find the least N. Sorry for not clarifying!

Comment: Presumably you mean “… faster than any **exponential** function?”

Comment: This response may be off point, because I am unsure of what you are asking.  If I have interpreted your question correctly: The geometric mean of $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ is always between $(n/e)$ and $(n/2)$ and in fact approaches $(n/e)$ from above, as $n \to \infty$.  So, the easy answer is that $N > eC$.

Comment: You know you don’t need the least $N$ for it to be true. Finding the least $N$ which works is in general, hard. But if $N(C)$ is the least value which works, you probably get $N(C)/C\to e$ as $C\to \infty.$

Comment: [Plot](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwryMkv0UhLTC7JL8pMzNGo0IzTMNSv0FTQVajQT9VR0DDUUTA0MNDUBAAOFgs6&lang=sage) of $(x!)^{1/x}-x/e$

Comment: A better approximation for $N$ is $Ce - (\ln(c) + 3)/2$. You can refine that approximation using Newton's method (and $N!=\Gamma(N+1)$). [Demo in Sage](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtkM1qwzAQhO96iql7WcVOjFN6qKmhpz5FMSj6CaLJJigR2G_flSl1C92L0Ow3IzGPeI_swD34AQPsyCrIeTTns6Gp7vRIXTtp5Yoadi6GQFqpt8h3n4y9K-cDQmZLdtjrXkEmC0oeG1hsQScmq1HjSbd7vWNxFyZcEiIiIxk-enr5tpaZy0s0DXmly7gltkTOGi3cP8g1ybcoNqj6qkFuMDdiW_cZ9SDCzz0GmMONBMGrLDfo_LZ77nFI3nwqtUZWH8wYSqb-rUplixqkiEuK5kRZ_wGkzgWwY9ZfM_lZDA==&lang=sage)